# Can I write and read a parallel EEPROM content with Analog Discovery 2?

Tags: eeprom, c++, java

I am wondering if I can read or write the contents of a parallel EEPROM (e.g., 28C64) using Analog Discovery 2. Is C/C++ necessary for this purpose, or is Java sufficient (since AD2 allows scripting in this language)? Alternatively, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes. The Analog Discovery 2 provides a [SDK API](https://digilent.com/reference/test-and-measurement/guides/waveforms-sdk-getting-started) to control the digital pins directly. To quote the website `The SDK is available to use with C/C++, C#, Python, and Visual Basic through a dynamic library`. You can find the documentation for the digital I/O of the Python version [here](https://pydwf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pydwf_api/DwfDevice.digitalIO.html). There are limitation though:

- There are only 16 I/O pins on the Analog Discovery 2
- The pins are 3.3V (but 5V tolerant)
- The interface is quote `low-speed`

Alternatively, you could use an 5V Arduino which would be compatible with the 28C64. Here is an [article from digikey](https://www.digikey.de/en/maker/blogs/2019/how-to-use-parallel-eeprom-for-storing-data) that describes how to use an Arduino Mega.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these invaluable informations. It helps a lot!